python blob extractor from a sql query not working properly
im making a blob extractor to get some images from a db with a query for the following rows:
rows selected from query
so im using the following code to extract said images:
import psycopg2
import base64

# Conectar a la base de datos
conn = psycopg2.connect(user="serverinfo") 

cursor = conn.cursor()
# Ejecutar la consulta
cursor.execute('Select "id", "name", "flip_image" from product_template where flip_image is not null')
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
        product_id = row[0]
        product_name = row[1]
        image_data = row[2]
                
        if image_data:
                # Decodificar la imagen base64
                image_bytes = base64.b64decode(image_data)
                
                #Guardar la imagen en un archivo
                with open(f"{product_id}.png", 'wb') as image_file:
                        image_file.write(image_bytes)
                print(f"imagen {product_name} (ID: {product_id})guardada.")
                
cursor.close()
conn.close()

as it is right now the code is working and i get all the image files as long as i have
with open(f"{product_id}.png", 'wb') as image_file:
but when i try to change the product_id to product_name to print all the pngs with the actual name of the image instead of an id using
with open(f"{product_name}.png", 'wb') as image_file:
or
with open(f"{product_id}_{product_name}.png", 'wb') as image_file:
i get a no file error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Caja Registradora Casio Pcr-t280 / 1200 Items Con Nombre.png'
Why would the extraction work only with the product id variable and not the product name variable?

There is a slash in the product name.  That confounds open() because it looks for a directory called Caja Registradora Casio Pcr-t280 

Thanks, i didnt saw this, what would be the proper way to bypass the slash in open function? i bypassed it for now just getting rid of the "/" in the products because they were redundant in most cases.
